# java applet - delete ("java.io.tmpdir")+"myfolder" contents on closing applet or stop()

Tags: java, file, applet, java-io, temporary-files

I am trying to clear the myfolder contents (having some jars) which I wrote in java.io.tmpdir for the applet temporary use.
Now, when I am trying to delete the contents(jar's) on void stop() method  with below code:

```
 public void stop()
{
 File directory = new File (System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+"JarClassLoader");
                 // Get all files in directory
                    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
                    for (File file : files)
                    {

                        // Delete each file
                        if (!file.delete())
                        {   
                            // Failed to delete file
                    }
                }
}
```

It's not clearing anything or maybe OS is holding these jar's. Everytime I run an applet, these jar's keep on increasing..is there any way to delete these contents on applet stop?

Comment: Does it enter the `// Failed to delete file` block ? Are you sure you're not holding something (like executing classes in your JVM) from those jars ?

Comment: Need to know a lot more before can offer a reasonable answer.  Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  And please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: yes, it's going into failed to delete file block until i logs out and relogin into my application. After relogin, and loading the applet first time, then it's deleting all prior files on void stop().
But for the same session, even if manually I am trying to delete those jar files..I'm not able to, Windows OS has made a hold over them..
I want to know, I have already migrated away from the applet..den Why OS is still holding these jar's..is there any way to release or clean up  all temp contents that applet is using by overriding void destroy() method?

Comment: I'll look at it more closely when you get that SSCCE together.  BTW - add @PersonName to comments to notify the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
File directory = new File (System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+"JarClassLoader");
```

That should be:

```
File directory = new File (System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "JarClassLoader");
```